# How do I implement zoom.js to turn.js?

Tags: javascript, html, web, frameworks, turn.js

The result should be as follows:

If I click on a random page of my turn.js magazine, it should zoom in and zoom out of the page. The best example how I imagine it is [here](http://turnjs.com/#samples/magazine1)

Comment: Can you post your code which shows your attempt at making it work?

Comment: I just made some text pages with the basic script from turn.js, so it can work. I embedded zoom.min.js to my HTML.

Comment: You are more likely to receive an answer or some type of help if you post what you have already done.  You're essentially asking someone for a solution without showing any type of work done on your part.  Here's a link with some tips on how to ask your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Explain me how my recent code should help you. I just asked how to implement zoom.js. And like I wrote before, I just made some text pages. There is nothing important to show

Comment: Your code shows people what you have done so they can see if there's an issue with it or not.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the GitHub repo that has documentation on how to implement zoom.js.

https://github.com/hakimel/zoom.js